# Particle Double slit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

How was the Particle Double Slit Experiment really done? To be precise, what kind of double slits were used and how can such slits be small enough, especially for electrons and buckys balls?

Comment: Not exactly a *double* slit but electron diffraction by crystals is related.  In that case the rows of atoms in the crystal act as multiple slits.

Comment: One can use a wire at high voltage. This acts as a biprism. I think that is how they did C$_{60}$ in Aarhus.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a description](http://www.diyphysics.com/2013/04/02/in-memoriam-dr-akira-tonomura-1942-2012/) of the single electron experiment

[image: tanamura dblslit]

> This figure from our book “Exploring Quantum Physics Through Hands-On Projects” shows a schematic representation of the modifications that Tonomura made to a transmission electron microscope to develop his experimental setup. Electrons are emitted from a very sharp tungsten tip by applying a potential difference of 3 to 5kV between the tip and a first anode ring through an effect known as “field emission.” These electrons are then accelerated to the second anode potential of 50kV (*the de Broglie wavelength for the accelerated electrons is λ=0.0055nm)*. Assorted “electron optics” within the modified electron microscope attenuate and focus the electron beam so that a current of barely 1,000 electrons per second is beamed towards the double-slit.
>
> The double-slit is actually an extremely fine *wire filament (1μm diameter)* placed between two conductive plates a *centimeter apart.* The wire is biased at a positive voltage of 10V relative to the plates. This arrangement is known as an electron biprism.

Italics mine

[This link](http://www.hitachi.com/rd/portal/highlight/quantum/doubleslit/index.html) has a [video](http://www.hitachi.com/rd/portal/highlight/quantum/movie/video2a.html)