# What is the difference between the J.P Thomsons and double slit experiments for particle wave duality in electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

My textbook is very unclear on why the dual particle wave in electrons was discovered by the Thomson experiment. I don't understand why they first show me the Thomson experiment for the proof of this phenomenon and then state that the double slit experiment actually confirmed the theory. Also I don't understand how the Thomson experiment even works, I just know that the electrons are send to a little Sheed of gold which follows by some the electrons going through the Sheed and forming a interference pattern. However I do not understand why the electrons do this since there is no slit. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Diffraction patterns from crystals are seen routinely in scanning and transmission electron microscopes. The wavelength of the electrons are such that they diffract from the symmetric configuration of the crystalline atoms.

Comment: This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN-wjj_phVA for light. The difference with a double slit with electrons set up here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457548/particle-double-slit/457632#457632 and the wave nature here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/685051/is-my-understanding-of-the-double-slit-experiment-correct/685056#685056 . It aint simple, it needs mathematics.

Comment: On a slightly off-topic note: I would suggest that you ignore language about wave/particle duality in textbooks. What is true is that ensembles of quantum systems (like free electrons) show wave-like interference effects. What is not true is that this is the only interesting physics they are showing. To quote MIT's Allan Adams: "Many electrons don't make waves, they make cheese.". Experiments like the double slit or diffraction on crystals are merely meant to select the wave character of quantum systems while ignoring more complex properties (like spin, pair production etc.).

Comment: Are you sure it is called "Thomson experiment"? Don't you mean the Rutherford gold foil experiment?

Comment: @JánLalinský  There is one double slit called that, see the video in my comment

Comment: [G P Thomson electron diffraction with gold foil](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/1937/thomson/facts/)

Comment: @Farcher correct , old age shows, I made the same mistaken association

Comment: @annav Welcome to the club!